# I need to find out how to limit the total cart size in a Wix shop

Tags: javascript, cart

I have no idea about coding. I hope you can help. I have a done a small course in JS, and i found it utterly baffling.

However, I am trying to set up an ecommerce site, which is contingent on me selling in mixed quantities, but to a maximum of 12 in a cart (I'm selling bottles of wine, and the boxes take 12 bottles). The site is built in Wix (I am a complete newbie), and they don't seem to have this purchase limit functionality. Is there a workaround?

Help! (and thank you)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks - I've tried the help centre, and good old google. I was hoping there was some easy cut and paste javascript I could fling on there saying " you have exceeded your maximum number of bottles for a case" (or " there's not enough wine in your case" in the case of too little) when they try to checkout... but I',m seriously out of my depth - I wouldn't know where to start! Wix's solution is to only allow purchases in batches of 12... but that means I cannot offer mixed cases.